# can't receive UDP broadcast in windows 10 UWP from android app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, broadcast, udpclient

- I'm writing UWP and Android apps using Xamarin.forms & .net Standard 2 for shared code.
- I'm trying to send and receive UPD boradcast from both apps, but the problem is that I can send and receive as expected from the android app only, and the UWP app can't receive the UDP broadcast packet?
- I installed wireshark on windows and it can receive all the packages from the two apps.
- I added firewall rule for my app.uwp.exe (allow any network, any port,any protocol, any ip) I restarted the pc and my UWP app still can't receive from the android app.

The code:

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;    

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
    {
     public async static Task<String> UDP_receive()
     {
        var myUDP = new UdpClient(8888);
        myUDP.EnableBroadcast = true;            
        var myResult = await myUDP.ReceiveAsync();
        myUDP.Close();
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myResult.Buffer) + " : " + myResult.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();
     }

     public async static Task UDP_Send()
     {
        var myUDP = new UdpClient();
        var RequestData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        myUDP.EnableBroadcast = true;
        await myUDP.SendAsync(RequestData, RequestData.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 8888));
        myUDP.Close();
     }
    void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        StartListen();
        StartSending();   
     }
     async Task StartListen()
     {
        Exception eXX = null;
        while (eXX == null)
        {
            try
            {
                myText.Text += Environment.NewLine + await UDP_receive();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                eXX = ex2;
                log(ex2);
            }
        }
     }

     async Task StartSending()
     {
        Exception eXX = null;
        while (eXX == null)
        {
            try
            {
                await MyData.UDP_Send();
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                eXX = ex2;
                log(ex2);
            }
        }
     } 
   }
```

Android output:
11:57:11 AM : 192.168.1.155
11:57:11 AM : 192.168.1.**100**
11:57:12 AM : 192.168.1.155
11:57:12 AM : 192.168.1.**100**
11:57:13 AM : 192.168.1.155
11:57:13 AM : 192.168.1.**100**
....
Note: 192.168.1.100 is the Windows PC IP

UWP output:
11:57:11 AM : 192.168.1.100
11:57:12 AM : 192.168.1.100
11:57:13 AM : 192.168.1.100
11:57:14 AM : 192.168.1.100
11:57:15 AM : 192.168.1.100
....

Comment: You have a form project and there is no need to block since the the is a built in block in the Form constructor.  So remove the await (not needed).  Also remove the myUDP.Close();  It looks like when you receive the first data you are closing the connection.

Comment: thanks for your effort,I tried your suggestions but they didn't solve my problem. My UWP already receives its sent data, but it don't receive android sent data.

Comment: There may be another app using the port number or it may be blocked by a firewall or virus checker.  I would use cmd.exe >Netstat -a and check if the port number is already being used.  Port numbers are registered events and the first application on the event list for the port number gets the message unless if is registered in a group (usually a multicastgroup).  But you are not using a multicast IP (224 to 239).

Comment: the UWP receives its UDP broadcast packets when lestening to port 8888, the android app however receives both its packet and UWP's packets

Comment: @jdweng , when I ran Netstat -a I got : UDP 0.0.0.0:8888 only when my UWP is running

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is IP.Any  which is good.  I assume it is in the Established state since you are connected.  I haven't used Broadcast in a long time.  From the documentation you have to use Connect() after turning Broadcast ON.  Not sure why the send is working without using CONNECT() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive UDP broadcasts, try separating the creation from the binding. For example,

```
            var myUDP = new UdpClient()
            {
                ExclusiveAddressUse = false,
                EnableBroadcast = true
            };

            IPEndPoint localIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(myIP.BroadcastIPAddress, 8888);
            myUDP.Client.Bind(localIPEndPoint);
```

From my experience, it appears the short form constructors, like UdpClient(8888), binds the underlying socket too early. This prevents changing the EnableBroadcast property.

As well, from platform to platform, I've found the only reliable way to receive broadcasts is to use the actual broadcast address for the subnet. Capturing that tidbit of information is easily done (?) as shown below.

```
    public class BroadcastAddress
    {
        public IPAddress IPAddress { get; set; }
        public IPAddress BroadcastIPAddress { get; set; }
        public NetworkInterfaceType NetworkInterfaceType { get; set; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<BroadcastAddress> GetBroadcastAddresses()
    {
        List<BroadcastAddress> broadcastAddresses = new List<BroadcastAddress>();

        NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in networkInterfaces)
        {
            if (networkInterface != null 
                && (networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211
                ||  networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet))
            {
                IPInterfaceProperties iPInterfaceProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
                UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection unicastIPAddressInformationCollection = iPInterfaceProperties.UnicastAddresses;
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation unicastIPAddressInformation in unicastIPAddressInformationCollection)
                {
                    if (unicastIPAddressInformation.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        IPAddress broadcastIPAddress = 
                            new IPAddress(unicastIPAddressInformation.Address.Address | (UInt32.MaxValue ^ (UInt32)(unicastIPAddressInformation.IPv4Mask.Address)));

                        broadcastAddresses.Add(new BroadcastAddress()
                        {
                            IPAddress = unicastIPAddressInformation.Address,
                            BroadcastIPAddress = broadcastIPAddress,
                            NetworkInterfaceType = networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return broadcastAddresses;
    }
```

When you are dealing with a mobile device, you would just use the Wireless80211 broadcast address. On a laptop or workstation it can become slightly more complicated. These devices can have multiple network interfaces AND multiple subnets on each interface. Hence, the reason for a list being returned. And, that means you may need to have multiple UdpClient instances, one for each subnet.

This is likely too late for the OP. Hopefully, this information helps some other weary searcher trying to get broadcasts working (and they can stop pounding their forehead on the desk).

Comment: Trying to use this to receive UDP broadcasts in a Xamarin.Forms app on UWP.  If I bind to the broadcast address returned from your code (which looks correct, addr: 192.168.109.100, broadcastAddr: 192.168.109.255), the Bind call throws a socket exception, "The requested address is not valid in its context".  If I bind to IPAddress.Any, no exception, but I don't receive any data.

Comment: @Nerdtron Please open a new question so we can easily share code fragments. Off the top of my head the only thing that comes to mind is the order of calls. Also, if you reference a posters name in a comment, they'll get notified sooner. ;-)

Comment: I created a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420560/unable-to-receive-udp-broadcast-in-xamarin-forms-app.  I was able to get it working and posted details there.  Ended up just using IPAddress.Any.

Comment: I referenced your name, but it appeared to remove that reference from my comment...  And it did it again.  I think that if you reference the name of the comment author to which you're replying it strips it out as unnecessary as they get notified already.