# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Network is unreachable

Tags: sockets, xamarin.forms, wifimanager, udpclient

I have commands that work properly on lower version Android, but since WiFi Manager changed the config command in Android 10 and above, my command does not respond and gives an error, please help me!

connectivityManager Android 10 :

```
WifiNetworkSuggestion guestUsers = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
               .SetSsid("########")
               .SetWpa2Passphrase("#######")
               .Build();
            var suggestions = new[] { guestUsers };
            var status = wifiManager.AddNetworkSuggestions(suggestions);
var specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                            .SetSsid("##########")
                            .SetWpa2Passphrase("###########")
                            .Build();
                    var request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                                        .AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi) // we want WiFi
                                        .RemoveCapability(NetCapability.Internet) // Internet not required
                                        .SetNetworkSpecifier(specifier) // we want _our_ network
                                        .Build();
                    var connectivityManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService) as ConnectivityManager;
                    var callback = new NetworkCallback
                    {
                        NetworkAvailable = network =>
                        {
                            re = true;
                        }
                    };
                    connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, callback);
```

UdpClient Defult:

```
using (var client = new UdpClient())
                        {
                            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), sendPort);
                            client.Connect(ep);
                            client.Send(test, test.Length);
                        }
```

Error Catch:

{System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Network is unreachable
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b0] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:892
at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint endPoint) [0x00033] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs:477
at SmartCube.DeviceFolder.Connection.SocketUdp () [0x00071] in }

note :

Let me remind you again, this command works for Android 10 and below, and there is no problem, it does not work due to the Wi-Fi Manager update of Android 10 and above.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420560/unable-to-receive-udp-broadcast-in-xamarin-forms-app

Comment: Unfortunately . My problem was not solved

Comment: @Amiroid Hi, do you have a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58769623/android-10-api-29-how-to-connect-the-phone-to-a-configured-network ?

Comment: Junior Jiang - MSFT  TNK For Help.But He could not help me

Answer (score 1):

If your app targets Android 10 or higher, and it isn't a system app or a DPC, then the following methods don't return useful data:

- The `getConfiguredNetworks()` method always returns an empty list.
- Each network operation method that returns an integer value—`addNetwork()` and `updateNetwork()`—always returns -1.
- Each network operation that returns a boolean value—`removeNetwork()`, `reassociate()`, `enableNetwork()`, `disableNetwork()`, `reconnect()`, and `disconnect()`—always returns `false`.

If your app needs to connect to Wi-Fi networks, use the following alternative methods:

- To trigger an instant local connection to a Wi-Fi network, use `WifiNetworkSpecifier` in a standard `NetworkRequest` object.
- To add Wi-Fi networks for consideration for providing internet access to the user, work with `WifiNetworkSuggestion` objects. You can add and remove networks that appear in the auto-connect network selection dialog by calling `addNetworkSuggestions()` and `removeNetworkSuggestions()`, respectively. These methods don't require any location permissions.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I did all this, , I still have errors